# plugin is not installed error even after plugins installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic6

I have upgraded my ionic mobile APP. Post update, my app is showing "plugin is not installed". But i have installed all required plugins. But still am getting "plugin is not installed" error. Please help me out

```
Native: tried calling Diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled, but the Diagnostic plugin is not installed.


Install the Diagnostic plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic'
```

Above error is being thrown when i access some functions from that plugin.

Note : I am using **awesome-cordova-plugins** for native purpose.

```
import { Diagnostic } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/diagnostic/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Diagnostic],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the installation step correctly on https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic